# Не происходит миграция при первом запуске приложения

Tags: android, sqlite, orm, миграция

Не происходит миграция при первом запуске приложения. Однако, если это будет просто обновление приложения, то миграция успешно выполнится. Пытался гуглить, ничего, объясняющее такой "прикол", не нашёл.

Использую ORM actvieandroid.

Comment: Если приложение устанавливается с нуля, то никакая миграция и не нужна. Просто будет установлена последняя версия БД. Это как обновление приложения. Вы же из плей маркета сразу последнюю версию скачиваете, а не самую старую с последующим обновлением:)

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov Не совсем понимаю. Допустим есть приложение в Маркете. В его обновлении с помощью миграции была изменена какая-то таблица. У тех, кто просто обновит приложение, эти изменения будут. А как же те, кто скачают в первый раз приложение? У них же не будет изменения.

Comment: Нет, у них сразу будет последняя версия. Вы используете фреймворк, он умеет создать сразу нужную БД. Но если есть старая БД и ее надо изменить, то это уже приходится решать через миграцию.

Answer (score 0):

Из [документации](https://github.com/pardom-zz/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Schema-migrations) ActiveAndroid:

> ActiveAndroid will execute a script if its filename is greater than the old database-version and smaller or equal to the new version.

Перевод:

> ActiveAndroid выполнит скрипт если имя файла, содержащего его (скрипт) больше, чем текущая версия базы данных и меньше или равна текущей версии.

Очевидно, что если старой версии нет, то условие выполниться не может.

Comment: Так если старая версия же есть, то есть изначально заполненная база данных?

Comment: @shahbazly сначала фреймворк создаст БД, а уже потом Вы сможете в ней что-то менять / заполнять данными по умолчанию.

Comment: pre-populated database я имею ввиду. Изначально имеется pre-populated, но нужно бы поменять в ней строку с помощью миграции.

Comment: @shahbazly в установочном файле должна лежать уже самая последняя версия БД в таком случае